# Bash syntax in /etc/profile

Tags: linux, bash, unix, sh, profile

I just noticed this line in my `/etc/profile`, and I wondered what this if means and when it is true.

```
if [ "${-#*i}" != "$-" ]; then
```

`i` iterates over several `*.sh` files.

Sorry if this is a silly question, but as you can imagine, looking for mostly symbols in Google is really not an option.

Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

From the `OPTIONS` section of the manpage:

```
-i        If the -i option is present, the shell is interactive.
```

From the `Special Parameters` section of the manpage:

> ```
>   -      Expands  to  the  current option flags as specified upon invoca-
>          tion, by the set builtin command, or  those  set  by  the  shell
>          itself (such as the -i option).
> ```

From the `Parameter Expansion` section of the manpage:

> ```
>   ${parameter#word}
>   ${parameter##word}
> ```
>
> The word is expanded to produce a pattern just  as  in  pathname
>                expansion.  If the pattern matches the beginning of the value of
>                parameter, then the result of  the  expansion  is  the  expanded
>                value of parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘‘#’’
>                case) or the longest matching pattern (the ‘‘##’’ case) deleted.
>                If parameter is @ or *, the pattern removal operation is applied
>                to each positional parameter in turn, and the expansion  is  the
>                resultant  list.   If parameter is an array variable subscripted
>                with @ or *, the pattern removal operation is  applied  to  each
>                member  of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant
>                list.

So `"${-#*i}"` says expand the `$-` variable and remove from the start of the string until the letter `i`. That expansion is then compared `!=` against the expansion of `$-` (the same variable only unmodified).

When those are not the same it means the first expansion removed some contents which means the letter `i` appeared in the value of `$-` which means that (since `-i` is not an argument to `set`) that the `-i` argument was passed to the shell and the shell is an interactive shell.